# WITH cte UPDATE SET with WHERE breaks

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempList

CREATE TABLE #TempList (
    VarName NVARCHAR(10) ,
    VarValue NVARCHAR(10),
    VarValueNext NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #TempList 
    VALUES ('Fred',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Wilma',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Barney',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Betty',NULL, NULL)

;WITH cte_name AS (
SELECT * 
    FROM #TempList
)

UPDATE cte_name
    SET cte_name.VarValue = 'Fred' WHERE cte_name.VarName = 'Wilma' OR cte_name.VarName = 'Barney'
--      , cte_name.VarValueNext = 'Pebbles' WHERE cte_name.VarValue = 'Fred' and cte_name.VarName = 'Wilma'

SELECT * 
    FROM #TempList
```

I understand this is a simple example that does not warrant using a CTE construct.  I am trying to understand how the UPDATE block is impacted.

I would like to SET the value of a number of fields.  As soon as I introduce the WHERE clause, it appears I can only SET a single value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Thys

Comment: What seems to be the problem?, this runs just as you want it to

Comment: Because an update statement can only have a single where clause. In this situation I think you would want to use a case expression.

Comment: @Lamak they are talking about the second column in the update (which is currently commented out).

Comment: @SeanLange Ah, yeah, I see now. And the answer is as you said it. It has nothing to do with using a `CTE` though, so op seems to be confused

Comment: Add expected result.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks ok lights came on -- ONE WHERE per UPDATE, not per SET.  Thanks.  How do I set your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use a case expression here not a where clause. Remember that a where clause filters the rows in your query. I think you are a little confused on the syntax of things there. Here is how this type of update would look.

```
UPDATE cte_name
    SET VarValue = case when VarName IN('Wilma', 'Barney') then 'Fred' else VarName end
      , VarValueNext = case when VarValue IN('Wilma', 'Barney') then 'Pebbles' else VarValueNext end
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Appreciate the help :)  ...a LOT confused, but it's getting better thanks to this forum!

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong you need something like this

```
UPDATE #TempList
SET    VarValue = CASE
                    WHEN VarName IN ( 'Wilma', 'Barney' ) THEN 'Fred'
                    ELSE VarValue
                  END,
       VarValueNext = CASE
                        WHEN VarValue IN ( 'Fred', 'Wilma' ) THEN 'Pebbles'
                        ELSE VarValueNext
                      END
WHERE  VarName IN ( 'Wilma', 'Barney' )
        OR VarValue IN ( 'Fred', 'Wilma' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sean Lange pointed out my error -- one WHERE clause per UPDATE, not per SET.

For completeness, here is a working solution.

Thanks for the help all -- much appreciated.   Some days... ;-)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempList

CREATE TABLE #TempList (
    VarName NVARCHAR(10) ,
    VarValue NVARCHAR(10),
    VarValueNext NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #TempList 
    VALUES ('Fred',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Wilma',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Barney',NULL, NULL), 
           ('Betty',NULL, NULL)

;WITH cte_name AS (
SELECT * 
    FROM #TempList
)

UPDATE cte_name
    SET cte_name.VarValue = 
                CASE
                    WHEN cte_name.VarName = 'Wilma' OR cte_name.VarName = 'Barney' 
                    THEN 'Fred'
                END 
        , cte_name.VarValueNext = 
                CASE
                    WHEN cte_name.VarName = 'Betty' OR cte_name.VarName = 'Wilma'
                    THEN 'Bosses'
                END 
SELECT * 
    FROM #TempList
```